# XMLReader ReadInnerXml yields unexpected results

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xmlreader

(.Net 4.5.2 64-bit)

In trying to parse the Outlook 2007 STIG from IASE (http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Documents/U_MicrosoftOutlook2007_V4R13_STIG.zip) using XmlReader.

I'm running into a small problem with XmlReader's ReadInnerXml() function that I don't understand (note that "path" is the path to the xml file contained in the referenced zip):

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
  {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      if (reader.Name.Equals("Rule") && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Found rule: " + reader.GetAttribute("id"));
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

The above code returns the following list of IDs, which is expected:

```
Found rule: SV-18181r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18188r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18203r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18602r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18213r1_rule
Found rule: SV-35249r3_rule
Found rule: SV-18641r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18655r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18657r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18663r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18667r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18671r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18673r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18675r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18677r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18679r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18681r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18683r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18685r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18687r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18689r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18708r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18710r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18712r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18729r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18731r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18735r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18743r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18749r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18752r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18766r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18775r3_rule
Found rule: SV-18779r3_rule
Found rule: SV-18838r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18840r1_rule
Found rule: SV-62707r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18842r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18844r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18846r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18848r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18850r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18852r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18910r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18912r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18916r2_rule
Found rule: SV-18918r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18920r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18935r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18946r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18948r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18950r2_rule
Found rule: SV-18958r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18960r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18962r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18964r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18970r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18978r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18980r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18985r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18988r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18990r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18992r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18995r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19005r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19010r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19012r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19014r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19018r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19023r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19026r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19028r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19030r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19032r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19038r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19040r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19042r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19050r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19435r1_rule
```

However, changing the code to:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
  {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      if (reader.Name.Equals("Rule") && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Found rule: " + reader.GetAttribute("id"));
        reader.ReadInnerXml();
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

changes the result to:

```
Found rule: SV-18181r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18188r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18203r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18602r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18213r1_rule
Found rule: SV-35249r3_rule
Found rule: SV-18641r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18655r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18657r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18663r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18667r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18671r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18673r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18675r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18677r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18679r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18681r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18683r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18685r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18687r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18689r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18708r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18710r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18712r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18729r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18731r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18735r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18743r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18749r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18752r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18766r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18775r3_rule
Found rule: SV-18779r3_rule
Found rule: SV-18838r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18840r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18842r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18844r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18846r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18848r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18850r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18852r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18910r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18912r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18916r2_rule
Found rule: SV-18918r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18920r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18935r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18946r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18948r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18950r2_rule
Found rule: SV-18958r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18960r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18962r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18964r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18970r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18978r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18980r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18985r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18988r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18990r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18992r1_rule
Found rule: SV-18995r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19005r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19010r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19012r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19014r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19018r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19023r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19026r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19028r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19030r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19032r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19038r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19040r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19042r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19050r1_rule
Found rule: SV-19435r1_rule
```

Can someone please explain why SV-62707r1_rule is missing when I call ReadInnerXml() on each Rule? Even better, could someone please describe how to get the inner XML string of all Rule elements without it skipping one of them?

Comment: I do not see a loop in your code. How does it read multiple elements?

Comment: Oops - I accidentally took the loop out trying to reduce the example code for the question. It's back in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you call `reader.Read()` on every iteration. So, when you hit `Rule` open element tag, you call `reader.ReadInnerXml()` method, which read whole `Rule` element, including end element tag. And right after that you call `reader.Read()` and skipping next node in document, and if next node is another `Rule` open element tag, then you miss it. As simple fix you can change `if` to `while` in your second code.

Comment: Ah, the Readinnerxml advances it to the next tag - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you look in the XML file (U_MicrosoftOutlook2007_V4R13_Manual-xccdf.xml) you will find this information attached to that code:

> Criteria: If the value BlockExtContent is REG_DWORD = 1, this is not a
> finding.
>
> Display external content and pictures in HTML eMail - Outlook.
>
> Malicious e-mail senders can send HTML e-mail messages with embedded
> Web beacons, which are pictures and other content from external
> servers that can be used to track whether specific recipients open the
> message. Viewing an e-mail message that contains a Web beacon provides
> confirmation that the recipient's e-mail address is valid, which
> leaves the recipient vulnerable to additional spam and harmful e-mail.
> By default, Outlook does not download external content in HTML e-mail
> and RSS items unless the content is considered safe. Content that
> Outlook 2007 can be configured to consider safe includes:
>
> • Content in e-mail messages from senders and to recipients defined in the Safe Senders and Safe Recipients lists.
>
> • Content from Web sites in Internet Explorer's Trusted Sites security zone.
>
> • Content in RSS items.
>
> • Content from SharePoint Discussion Boards.
>
> Users can control what content is considered safe by changing the options in the Automatic Download section of the Trust Center. If Outlook's default blocking configuration is overridden, in the Trust Center or by some other method, Outlook will display external content in all HTML e-mail messages, including any that include Web beacons.

You may be able to find out what is wrong from this.